# Shopware 6: Best Practice for Product Catalog Extension - Push vs. Pull?

Tags: shopware6

we want to integrate with shopware to allow big shopware clients via an extension to have their product catalog (just basic product parameters like sku, name, brand, price, categories) synced regularly to our system. It does not need to be real-time, it can be synced once a day or so.

I assume this is like the most standard integration and therefore wondered if there is a best practice? ie. is it better to regularly push from Shopware side to our API or better to pull from our side Shopware API?

Also I understood that the new App system for Shopware cloud can also be used on-premise and is more sustainable than the plugin system, correct?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As you describe the requirements I'd recommend pulling the data from Shopware in intervals you deem fit. The API should provide you with all the data you need and you have the option to filter and aggregate the data as necessary.

You could have a plugin with a task set to regularly frequent an API on your side and push the same data but you'd probably not benefit much from that approach.

The app system comes with the concept of [webhooks](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/references/app-reference/webhook-events-reference). These do include write operations for certain entities (like products). This would be an option if you absolutely needed to react in real time to persistance of data in real time. The downside could be the amount of requests dispatched to the external API but since you say you don't need to react to changes in real time that would probably be unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply! What i thought as downside of pulling is that the shopware client must give us the full API key (as far as i am aware there is no field level restriction of API keys) and thus gives away "control". While pushing from SW side would be more "control" of the data owner.

Would you still recommend pulling, when we would require in a future version Order data (without customer data), not necessarily real-time, but more frequent (eg. every hour, or every 10mins)?

Comment: With the Admin-API, integrations can be granulary restricted with roles and permissions. See the [documentation on integration settings](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/settings/system/integrationen). Unless you'll end up fetching data in intervals within single digit minutes or so, I think pulling data using the API is always preferable.